# Why is there data reduction when converting negative numbers to Nan in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Python programming process. I found that some of the data were negative when I processed the data by type (it may be that the missing part of the questionnaire was replaced by a negative number). So I decided to convert all negative numbers to Nan for processing. But I found that the data will decrease when I use the following code.

```
   for i, j in itertools.product(nothing_1, range(-9, 0)):
    df_orign[i].replace(j, np.NaN, inplace = True)
```

Nothing_ 1 represents the column label in the DataFrame
df_ origh for my dataframe

Comment: what do you mean by "data reduction" or "decrease"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.